# How to load .x model in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada, .x

Is there any way to load an animated .x model in Three.js? I have no idea, how to do it. In addition, I tried to convert the .x model to collada, but I haven't found any free program, which can convert animated .x to collada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.x is an ascii format so it shouldn't be very hard to parse/convert.

Alternatively you can use Blender 2.4x which has a .x importer and you can export an .obj that you can convert to json or another format that suits you.

By default in Blender 2.5x there is only an .x exporter that you can activate in the preferences. Maybe there's an importer available somewhere.

Comment: Which is ascii/human readable, as opposed to binary. Any luck with converting with an older version of Blender (2.45, etc.) ?